# Unity Prefabs: Asset import did not unload metadata path. This will leak memory

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I'm in Unity 2018.3, and I created a prefab of an object called "Water." I deleted the prefab and then used Ctrl+Z to unlink the prefab from the original. Now, whenever I make changes to the new prefab, I get this full message:

```
Asset import did not unload metadata path. This will leak memory. File a bug with repro steps please. (Assets/Prefabs/Water.prefab)
```

UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()

I would really appreciate it if this could be fixed, because it's annoying. Also, if anyone could give tips on how to unlink prefabs BEFORE delteing, that would be GREAT!

Thanks!!

Comment: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/error-message-asset-import-did-not-unload-metadata-path-this-will-leak-memory

Answer (score 0):

As of 2019.2.6f1 this issue still persists when unchecking "Import Materials" but wasn't going to be resolved.

IssueTracker says:

> RESOLUTION NOTE:
>       This issue happens only in AssetPipeline v1 which is deprecated in 2019.3 and doesn't exist in 2020.x, plus we don't think that this issue has a high priority as it happens rarely.